# Put money on (mutual funds,health insurance etc) to mean invest

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Is it natural to say:

> I ***put some money on*** mutual funds.
>
> I ***put some money on health*** insurance.(or any other insurance)

Is the use of "put some money on" natural?

Like:
I invested in mutual funds. 
I invested in health insurance.

Answer (score 3):

Put some money **into** or ***in*** mutual funds is natural (at least, for me). "Put money on..." sounds like a bet is being placed. For example, "I put $500.00 on Secretariat to come in first in the Preakness (race)."

> I invested in health insurance.

I would say this can be acceptable depending on what you mean. If you're talking about making money off an investment, then it is not correct. You invest in mutual funds because you hope to receive more money than you invested. You "invest" in health insurance because you want to be able to pay for health care. Your goal is not to make a financial gain. Normally one would say, "I obtained health insurance" or "I bought health insurance."

As your mastery of English increases, you will become more and more able to understand these distinctions.

Another example: "I invested in a good pair of eyeglasses." The person doesn't mean he hopes to make a profit from selling them, he means he's buying something that he hopes will serve a useful purpose.